# Net Core, Build own Identity Service, Users are confused

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core

I want to build own user login service without extra tables(no Net Core Identity).
When several users come in, the application shows a random user, but active, who uses it on another computer. How to make sure that an authorized user is not confused with other active users?

My Service:

```
public interface IUserIdentity
    {
        void Authenticate(string Login, string PasswordHash);
        Users GetActiveUser();
        string GetActiveUserName();
        string GetActiveUserPositionName();
        bool IsVisibleMainMenu();
        bool IsVisibleDistributionMenu();
        bool IsVisibleContractMenu();
        Users DeactivateUser();
    }

    public class UserIdentity : IUserIdentity
    {
        private Users user;
        private string userPosition;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
        public UserIdentity(IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
        {
            if (unitOfWorkFactory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(unitOfWorkFactory));

            _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
        }

        public void Authenticate(string Login, string PasswordHash)
        {
            using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory.MakeUnitOfWork())
            {
                user = unitOfWork.Users.GetUser(Login, PasswordHash);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var position = unitOfWork.Positions.Get(user.PositionId);
                    if (position != null)
                    {
                        userPosition = position.Name;
                    }
                    else userPosition = "";
                }
                else userPosition = "";
            }
        }
        public Users GetActiveUser()
        {
            return user;
        }

        public string GetActiveUserName()
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.FullName;
            }
            else return "";
        }

        public Users DeactivateUser()
        {
            user = null;
            return user;
        }

        public string GetActiveUserPositionName()
        {
            return userPosition;
        }

        public bool IsVisibleMainMenu()
        {
            const int CLERK_POSITION_ID = 18;
            const int ADMIN_ROLE_ID = 3;
            if (user.RoleId == ADMIN_ROLE_ID || user.PositionId == CLERK_POSITION_ID)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }

        public bool IsVisibleContractMenu()
        {
            const int SUPPLIER_ROLE_ID = 6;
            const int CLERK_POSITION_ID = 18;
            const int ADMIN_ROLE_ID = 3;
            if (user.RoleId == SUPPLIER_ROLE_ID || user.PositionId == CLERK_POSITION_ID ||  user.RoleId == ADMIN_ROLE_ID)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }

        public bool IsVisibleDistributionMenu()
        {
            const int CLERK_POSITION_ID = 18;
            if (user.PositionId!= CLERK_POSITION_ID)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }

    }
```

Startup:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IUserIdentity, UserIdentity>();
```

SignInController:

```
 public class SignInController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SignInController> _logger;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;
        private readonly IUserIdentity _userIdentity;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory _unitOfWorkFactory;
        private Users authorized_user;

        public SignInController(ILogger<SignInController> logger, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext, IUserIdentity userIdentity, IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
            _userIdentity = userIdentity;
            _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;
            
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Exit()
        {
            _userIdentity.DeactivateUser();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "SignIn");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(Users user)
        {
            const int SUPPLIER_ROLE_ID = 6;
            const int CLERK_POSITION_ID = 18;
            const int ADMIN_ROLE_ID = 3;
            if (user != null)
            {
                    _userIdentity.Authenticate(user.Login, user.Password.GetMd5Hash());
                    var authorized_user = _userIdentity.GetActiveUser();
                    if (authorized_user != null)
                    {
                        if (authorized_user.PositionId== CLERK_POSITION_ID || authorized_user.RoleId == ADMIN_ROLE_ID)
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Inbox", "Reception");
                        }
                        else if (authorized_user.RoleId==SUPPLIER_ROLE_ID)
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Contract", "Reception");
                        }
                        else return RedirectToAction("Inbox", "InboxDistributions");
                }
                    else return View();
            }
            else return View();
        }

    }
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<header>
            <div class="photo" height="300px" width="250px">
                <span class="image">
                   <img src=data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(@userIdentity.GetActiveUser().Photo) alt="">
                </span>


            </div>
            <div class="userData">
                <span class="name">@userIdentity.GetActiveUserName()</span>
                <span class="profession">@userIdentity.GetActiveUserPositionName()</span>
            </div>
            <i class='k-icon k-i-arrow-chevron-right toggle'></i>
        </header>
```

Comment: `.AddSingleton<IUserIdentity, UserIdentity>` with a single `Users user;` & `string userPosition;`. Yeah, that's not going to work. Did you want to make it scoped? If you don't want to use Identity, you still need to solve all the same problems, and it looks like you have no idea what those problems actually are.

Comment: Identity is a big complex framework, and I understand the desire to build something simpler. But there are ways to use parts of the built in authentication systems without using, or needing to re-invent everything. I'd recommend you start by reading everything under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0.